# Send byte at Regular interval to Client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, silverlight-4.0

I have an array of bytes which comes on the regular interval on the web server using web service from the client.
Now, I want to play that byte array which is actually an audio on the client as soon as I get on the server specifically in Silverlight.

Would it be possible to get byte stream and play it directly continously without affecting the stream?
In other words, can I append bytes to file or stream and play it simultaneously in silverlight or in `.NET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see IIS Smooth Streaming. Or see Http polling duplex or comet technology. see [Here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=smooth%20streaming&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming&ei=yarHTsmTHIPxrQfzvoGWDg&usg=AFQjCNHj3iBp9vOzGOtGRqLgslHbTWKipQ&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

So data (a sequence of byte arrays sent at intervals) is sent to a web server. A silverlight client also contacts the web server requesting a sequence of byte arrays which it will play as audio on receipt?

I don't think that's going to work. You can't guarantee a constant network speed which means you want a buffer on the client so you can play the 'byte array' contiguously.

Normally, the data would be sent to the service and saved, then a streaming client can connect to the resource and play the stream. Is there are reason you can't do this?

Comment: So, Can I have a file saved on the server and append coming bytes stream from client to the same file? So that I can assign that file url to silverlight application? Do you have any idea?

Comment: It would be good if I could append bytes to my existing or saved audio file and then clients would use that stream. Would it be possible? How? Are there any seeking position considerations when assigning new source of stream in media element?

Answer (score 0):

Consider researching long poll and comet approaches. Here's one article http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/08/performance-of-http-polling-duplex.html

Comment: is Http Polling duplex feasible for exchange of binary data? Is there any provision I can make an application just for two parties at one single time in silverlight?